# Two dimensional array allocation

Tags: c++

i have following code for allocation two dimensional array

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int **malloc2d(int r,int c){
    int **t=new int*[r];
     for (int i=0;i<r;i++)
         t[i]=new int[c];

      for (int i=0;i<r;i++){
           for (int j=0;j<c;j++){
                t[i][j]=i+j;
           }
      }
     return t;
     }

int main(){
    int m=10;
    int n=10;
    int **a=malloc2d(m,n);
     for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
          for (int j=0;j<n;j++){

              cout<<a[i][j]<< " ";
              cout<< " \n";
          }
          cout<< " \n";
     }


    return 0;


}
```

it works but my question is: how good    is  this code according to performance efficienty or  according to   code speed? thanks

Comment: Leaks, and is gross. You should wrap resources up, like `std::vector`. Until your program is correct, who cares about speed?

Comment: Again, please use the tab key to indent. Programming is much easier if you use an editor that supports tabs.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Indenting the problem, or tab-based indenting?  Cause there's religious wars about that...

Comment: @Merlyn: I'm talking about the tab key, not the tab character. Really, there are people who insist that they (or everyone) manually press the spacebar multiple times? Well, that's okay, but do it consistently!!

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Nah, they just insist that the editor spit out spaces when you hit the tab key.

Comment: What i wonder about: Is `n` and `m` *always* computed at runtime? If `n` is known at compile time, this can be much simplier and convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an `int **` you have lots of pointers to tiny (4 byte) memory spaces which is inefficient due to malloc overhead (every malloc implementation has an overhead, the minimum normally is `sizeof(void*)` AFAIK which in your case would mean there's at least a 100% overhead for all "cells").

As an alternative, you could use a one-dimensional array and calculate the indexes yourself like this: `index = (row * num_columns) + column`. You would lose the nice `a[row][column]` notation, though. Still, it should be faster to access as well because in your (clean) solution there have to be two pointer dereferences (memory operations) while in the way I suggest you only have one. It would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

inline int a_index(int row, int column, int column_size) {
        return((row * column_size) + column);
}

int *malloc2d(int r,int c) {
        int *t=new int[r * c];
        for (int i=0;i<r;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<c;j++){
                        t[a_index(i,j,c)]=i+j;
                }
        }
        return t;
}


int main(){
        int m=10;
        int n=10;
        int *a=malloc2d(m, n);
        for (int i=0;i<m;i++){
                for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
                        cout<<a[a_index(i,j,n)]<< " ";
                        cout<< " \n";
                }
                cout<< " \n";
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you plan to add `delete[]`, or the program will terminate before leakage matters.

Anyway, it won't be very efficient.

First, the array will be composed of non-contiguous blocks of memory. That makes it harder for the machine's memory subsystem to handle.

Second, some extra space is being wasted to hold the array of pointers.

Just do it the old fashioned way:

```
int *a = new int[ r * c ];
```

or with `vector`

```
std::vector<int> a( r * c );
```

and compute indexes as ever:

```
cout << a[ i * c + j ] << ' ';
```

However, since you are looping over the entire array, you could ignore the two-dimensionality except for formatting:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < r * c; ++ i ) {
    cout << a[ i ] << ' ';
    if ( i % c == c-1 ) cout << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't delete the memory that you have allocated by using new, then you will leak memory.

Comment: so in main   just write delete a  at the end of program and no problems?

Comment: @c-programmer: Until you forget, or work with more complicated code that may throw exceptions. You *really* need to take a step back, [get a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and learn good fundamentals.

Comment: @GMAN thanks i know but problem is that i have not money to buy books  which i need so  unfortunately   i have big problems with buy books

Comment: @c-programmer: Your library may have one available for you. Also, [these books](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) are free.

Comment: In fact, you'd likely have to mirror your allocation function for deletion, i.e., a loop of `delete[]` for each column, and then a final `delete[]`. Another reason why `vector` is such a nice thing.

Comment: at this moment  i am studing c++  from cplusplus.com

Comment: @c-programmer: Yes. Very rarely are online tutorials good. (For example, that site never touches on programming *practices*, just the language.And not too complete at all.)